# MVC Insert Partial View At The Top Of A Page On ActionLink Click

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have 3 Views(Well 1 and 2 Partials) - Index, _Archive, _ListItem

There is an archive button on _ListItem that is supposed to have a JS confirm popup, then if you click ok it is supposed to display a bootstrap success alert at the top of the page.

Here is the code in _ListItem for the archive button:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Archive", "_Archive", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm", onclick = "return confirm('You are about to mark \"" + @Model.Id + " - " + @Model.Name + "\" archived, are you sure you want to continue?');" })
```

Now the confirm works, but how do I get my Archive popup to popup at the top of the index page and not take me to a separate page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do some unobtrusive javascript to handle the click event.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Archive", "Index","Home", new { id = "Test" },
                        new{ @class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm confirm" })
```

And the javascript to handle the click event on the anchor tag

```
<script>
  $(function() {

       $(".confirm").click(function(e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          var yes = window.confirm('You are about to mark "' + @Model.Name +'" archived.');
          if (yes) {
                alert("show the popup now");
                // Here invoke the code to bring the model popup
           }

       });
  });
</script>
```